# Docker compose and volumes_from by container name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: 2.4
services:
  foo:
    image: ubuntu:focal
    container_name: oof
    volumes:
      - ./foo:/foo
  bar:
    image: ubuntu:focal
    container_name: rab
    volumes_from:
      - container:oof
```

With compose 1.29.2 and docker 20.10.8. But it does not start.
I get an error
`ERROR: Service "bar" mounts volumes from "oof", which is not the name of a service or container.`

How do I properly reference volumes by container name in compose?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to explicitly spell out the volumes you're reusing.  If the `foo` image has `VOLUME` directives, you'll also mount the automatically-created anonymous volumes; you also have no control over where the volumes will be mounted, and if the two containers aren't similar enough, there could be conflicts.  (This is essentially the logic behind [Compose file version 3 removing `volumes_from:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#upgrading).)

```yaml
version: 2.4
services:
  foo:
    volumes:
      - ./foo:/foo
  bar:
    volumes:
      - ./foo:/foo # or a different container path if that suits your needs
```

In general in Compose, you shouldn't need to manually specify `container_name:`.  Compose will generate unique container names, within the `docker-compose.yml` file if you need to refer to things you can use the service name, and there are `docker-compose` wrapper commands that know how to find the right container.  If you do need to use the [older `volumes_from:` syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#volumes_from) use the service name instead:

```yaml
version: '2.4' # does not work in version 3
services:
  foo:
    image: ...
    volumes:
      - ./foo:/foo
    # no container_name:
  bar:
    image: ...
    volumes_from: foo
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems reasonable. But I'm bothered when the manual tells me that I can do "a thing", and then reality tells me that I can not. I realize the example is convoluted.